# '...jQuery is not defined' when using webpack but jQuery is defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack

When attempting to load my bundled script file in the browser I get:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

Which is supposedly coming from the the [last line in my bundled `underscore-min.js` being the issue](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/blob/master/underscore-min.js):

```
}()
```

Which doesn't make any sense? I'm not sure if something with the source map file is leading me astray. My configuration is such in `webpack.config.js`:

```
entry: {
  main: [ 
    './js/jquery.min.js', 
    './js/other.js', 
    './js/other2.js', 
    './js/underscore-min.js'
  ]
},     

...

plugins: {
  ...
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    jquery: 'jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery',
  }),
  ...
}

...

externals: {
  'jquery': 'jQuery',
  'jQuery': 'jQuery',
}
```

And without the above, heaps of other packages freak out which depend on jQuery. Is there something unique about the `underscore-min.js` script that is causing this?

Comment: is the jquery js file stored in the defined location? is it readible by the webserver?

Comment: Yes, it is readable by webpack. Before adding the `ProvidePlugin` declaration other files were complaining they couldn't access jQuery but now this is the only one that does.

Answer (score -1):

Just remove `externals: {
  'jquery': 'jQuery',
  'jQuery': 'jQuery',
}`.

If you want to use `externals`,

```
entry: {
  main: [ 
    './js/jquery.min.js', 
    './js/other.js', 
    './js/other2.js', 
    './js/underscore-min.js'
  ]
},     

...

...

externals: {
  'jquery': {
     root:'jquery',
     commonjs2:'jquery',
     commonjs:'jquery',
     amd:'jquery'
   }
},
output:{
   ...
   libraryTarget:"umd"
}
```

And in your html,add the script tag
`<script src="some-resources/jquery.js"></script>`

Comment: If I remove this from externals, I receive other errors, `cannot resolve jquery in xxx.js` files.